# How to use %in% to make string replacements (str_replace) in R

Tags: r, str-replace

I am trying to find an elegant way to use %in% and str_replace() to clean up gender.  I know I can use regx() to do the same thing, but am looking at alternative ways to tackle the same problem.

My code is:

```
sex <- c("Male","girl","boy", "female")
male <- c("Male", "boy")
female <- c("girl", "female")
```

I know this code isn't right, but illustrates what I am trying to do

```
str_replace(sex, sex %in% male, "M")
str_replace(sex, sex %in% female, "F")
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `replace`, not `str_replace`:

```r
sex <- c("Male","girl","boy", "female")
male <- c("Male", "boy")
female <- c("girl", "female")

sex <- replace(sex, which(sex %in% male), "M")
sex <- replace(sex, which(sex %in% female), "F")
sex
#> [1] "M" "F" "M" "F"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: So simple!! Thanks!!